# When combining two files with awk, how can i get it to store correct data to update the correct fields?

Tags: bash, awk

Basically, I have two files, one with only 3 columns of data, and another with 15.  I'm updating the file with 15 columns based on data from the one with three, replacing columns 10 and 11 with 2 and 3.  However, it only seems to be copying the same data to all lines, rather than pulling the unique data for each one.

Sample data from file1.csv

```
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1
```

Sample data for file2.csv

```
345,stat2,date2
346,stat2b,date2b
347,stat2c,date2c
```

Result

```
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2,date2
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2b,date2b
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2c,date2c
```

Code:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR==NR{s = $2;d = $3 ;++a[$1];next} {if ( (a[$4])) {$10 = s;$11 = d;print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9 "," $10 "," $11 "," $12 "," $13 "," $14 "," $15} }' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

Comment: sample data and expected output from that data please. Good luck.

Comment: Sample data's added.

Comment: For the print, no.  I've tried a slight variation which has resulted in non-duplicate data, but it's not moving the correct data either.`awk -F ',' 'FNR==NR{s[FNR] = $2;d[FNR] = $3 ;++a[$1];next} {if ( (a[$4])) {$10 = s[FNR];$11 = d[FNR];print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9 "," $10 "," $11 "," $12 "," $13 "," $14 "," $15} }'`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     (FNR==NR){a[FNR]=$2; b[FNR]=$3}
     (FNR!=NR){$10=a[FNR]; $11=b[FNR]; print}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

It replaces columns 10 and 11, leaving other columns unchanged.

It produces:

```
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2,date2
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2b,date2b
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2c,date2c
```

Comment: You should have used `next` statement in first block, and this will not work in all case, I mean suppose if you reorder lines of any one files this fails, since what you are using is not associative array.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
$ cat file1
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1

$ cat file2
345,stat2,date2
346,stat2b,date2b
347,stat2c,date2c

$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next}$4 in A{print $0,A[$4]}' OFS=, file2 file1
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2,date2
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2b,date2b
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2c,date2c
```

**Better Readable Version**

```
# Set Field Separator comma
awk -F, '
          # FNR==NR is only true while reading first file (file2)
          FNR==NR{
                   # Build assicioative array on the first column of the file
                   # where array element is second column, output field separator and third column
                   A[$1]=$2 OFS $3

                   # Skip all proceeding blocks and process next line
                   next
                 }

          # Check index ($4 = column4) from second argument (file1) exists in array A 
          # if exists 1 (true) otherwise 0 (false)
          $4 in A{
                   # As long as above state is true
                   # print current line from file1 and array A contents
                   # corresponding to index $4
                   print $0,A[$4]
                 }
        ' OFS=, file2 file1   # Set output field separator comma
```

Comment: I've seen other people do this so you're not alone but I just can't wrap my head around why you'd want to init a variable AFTER the code that uses the variable (`awk '{do stuff with OFS}' OFS=, file`) instead of before it (`awk -v OFS=, '{do stuff with OFS}' file`), nor why you'd init 2 variables that you require to have same the value separately (`awk -F, -v OFS=, '...' file`) instead of simultaneously (`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ...' file`).

Answer (score 2):

With the sample input/output you've shown in your question, all you need is:

```
$ paste file1.csv file2.csv | sed -r 's/\t[^,]+//'      
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2,date2
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2b,date2b
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2c,date2c
```

or maybe:

```
$ join -t, -14 -21 -o '1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.2,2.3' file1.csv file2.csv
123456,type,45689,345,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2,date2
123457,type,45690,346,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2b,date2b
123458,type,45691,347,serv,FALSE,pure,stat1,date1,stat2c,date2c
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to show a more truly representative input/output set, e.g. with unordered and/or unmatched and/or differing numbers of lines.